# Why is the y-intercept of this calculus problem given like that in the solution?

Tags: calculus, chain-rule, tangent-line

Given the following problem:

> Let $f$ be the real-valued function defined by $f(x) = \sqrt{1+6x}$.
>
> Determine the slope of the line tangent to the graph of $f$ at $x=4$.
>
> Determine the y-intercept of the line tangent to the graph of $f$ at $x=4$.

For the life of my I can't work out why the solution to the $y$ intercept is given as $\frac{13}{5}$.

I've correctly solved $f'$ using the definition of a derivative formula (I got $\frac{3}{\sqrt{1+6x}}$) and do get the correct answer for the slope of the line tangent to $x=4$ (which is $\frac{3}{5}$) but the $y$ intercept for that line is definitely $3$ and not $\frac{13}{5}$. Where am I going wrong? This is the solution that is given by the authors:
[image]

Comment: When you ask why your answer differs from the expected one, it’s very helpful to show your work instead of simply declaring your result. That way, you’re not making people who want to help you guess where you might have gone wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say the tangent line is $y=mx+b$ with $m=\frac35$ and a point on it is $(x,y)=(4,5).$

Can you solve for $b$?

Comment: Ah, but isn't the y-intercept defined at $x=0$?

Comment: Yes, the solution is $b=\frac{13}5$ so the equation for tangent line is $y=\frac35x+\frac{13}5$, and, when $x=0$, $y=\frac{13}5$

Comment: I gave the slope-intercept form of the line ($b$ is the y-intercept)

Comment: Right, I get it, $y=3$ is the y-intercept of the derivative, not the tangent line (I plotted the two of them and it now makes sense).